Platform Events LWC Subscription not listening on Service Cloud
Hi I have tested this same code and setup in a sales cloud playground, and it works smoothly.
However when I move the code to a Partner Developer Edition Service Cloud. The LWC Is not receiving the events on the platform events channel, it subscribes successfully and publish successfully but it is not receiving any messages.
Apex:
public with sharing class PlatformEventsHandler {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static UserInfoWrapper getCurrentUser(){
        Id userId = UserInfo.getUserId();
        User currentUser = [SELECT Id, Name, UserName
                            FROM User
                            WHERE Id = :userId];
        UserInfoWrapper uiw = new UserInfoWrapper();
        uiw.id = currentUser.Id;
        uiw.name = currentUser.Name;
        uiw.userName = currentUser.UserName;
        uiw.status = 'Active';
        return uiw;
    }
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Boolean publishUserEvent(String instanceId, String name, String eventType, 
                                                   String status, String target, String recipient) {
        Boolean success = true;
        try {
            CaseMonitorEvent cme = new CaseMonitorEvent();
            cme.insatnceId = instanceId.split('-')[0];
            cme.name = name;
            cme.status = status;
            cme.target = target;
            cme.eventType = eventType;
            String payload = JSON.serialize(cme);
            Case_Monitor_Event__e event = new Case_Monitor_Event__e(
                Payload__c = payload
            );
            EventBus.publish(event); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug(e.getMessage());
            success = false;
        }
        return success;
    }

    public class CaseMonitorEvent {
        @AuraEnabled
        public Id insatnceId { get; set; }
        @AuraEnabled
        public String name { get; set; }
        @AuraEnabled
        public String status { get; set; }
        @AuraEnabled
        public String eventType { get; set; }
        @AuraEnabled
        public String target { get; set; }
        @AuraEnabled
        public String recipient { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserInfoWrapper {
        @AuraEnabled
        public Id id { get; set; }
        @AuraEnabled
        public String name { get; set; }
        @AuraEnabled
        public String status { get; set; }
        @AuraEnabled
        public String userName { get; set; }
        @AuraEnabled
        public String target { get; set; }
        @AuraEnabled
        public String type { get; set; }
    }
}

LWC:
import { LightningElement, track, wire, api } from 'lwc';
import { subscribe, unsubscribe } from 'lightning/empApi';
import publishUserEvent from '@salesforce/apex/PlatformEventsHandler.publishUserEvent';
import getCurrentUser from '@salesforce/apex/PlatformEventsHandler.getCurrentUser';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { CurrentPageReference } from 'lightning/navigation';

export default class CasesMonitor extends LightningElement {

    @api recordId;
    channelName = '/event/Case_Monitor_Event__e';
    subscription = {};
    membersMap = {};
    @track activeUsersList = [];
    usersEventsQueue = [];
    status;
    isUpdatingData = false;
    idleWarningDispatched = false;
    instanceId;
    recordHRef;
    userName;
    onURL = true;;

    @wire(CurrentPageReference)
    currentPageReference;

    disconnectedCallback() {
        this.removeWindowListeners();
        unsubscribe(this.subscription, response => {
            console.log('Unsubscribed from channel: ', JSON.stringify(response));
        });
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        this.recordHRef = window.location.href;
        this.subscribeToEvent();
        this.addWindowListeners();
    }

    subscribeToEvent() {
        this.subscription = subscribe(this.channelName, -1, (event) => { this.handleEvent(event) })
        .then(response => {
            this.notifyConnection();
        });
    }

    handleEvent(event) { // this is the function that never gets called despite of events being published
        console.log('Event Received');
    }

    async notifyConnection() {
        const userInfo = await getCurrentUser();
        const { id, status, name } = userInfo;
        
        this.status = status;
        this.instanceId = id + '-' + this.recordId;
        this.userName = name;
        const instanceId = this.instanceId;

        publishUserEvent({ instanceId, name, status, eventType: 'Connection', target: 'All', recipient: null })
        .then((response) => {console.log(response)})
        .catch((err) => console.error(err));
        this.startIdleCounter();
    }

    startIdleCounter() {
        console.log('starting idle counter');
    }
}

The Platform Event setup is identical in both orgs (Playground and Service Cloud Instance)
I dont know if Im missing a permission or any special configuration on Service Cloud for this LWC to be able to listen the published platform events.
Is it because its a Partner Developer Edition or something? Please help me

How are you sure that subscribe has actually subscribed to the platform event?
Can you console.log the response to make sure there is no handshake error?

@NagendraSingh there is a console log in .then within the notifyConnection function. that always shows true

Notifyconnection  as per current code will always get called, can you also add a console.log in subscribe method and check the result once as suggested in first comment.

@NagendraSingh {channel: "/event/Case_Monitor_Event__e"id: "_1713281926452_5097"replayId: -1}
